# ASP.NET - Model does not exist

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems with using a foreach and a HTML list in a view. The controller calls a service which returns IEnumerable of a number of items, and I'm trying to display these items as a HTML list in my view.

However, I'm getting "CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context" on line 7 of my view. As far as I'm aware I've got the right syntax for displaying things from the model.

What is going wrong?

I have a model like this:

```
public class NewsItem
{
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    NewsReader newsReader = new NewsReader();
    var newsItems = newsReader.GetNewsItems();

    return View(newsItems);
}
```

and my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<Site.Services.News.NewsItem>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@foreach(var item in model)
{
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.DisplayFor(m => model.Title)</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should capitalize "model" and use "item" in your DisplayFor:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Title)</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, the model property is pascal cased, so should be `Model`.

Second, it is of type `IEnumerable<NewsItem>` so wouldn't have the property `Title` and would not relate to the individual `item` you are iterating. Your lambda expression should reference `item`.

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Title)</li>
    </ul>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For .aspx page in  MVC :-

```
<table>
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
<tr><td><%= item.title %></td></tr>
<% } %>
</table>
```

For Razor Engine Pages in MVC :-

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
<ul>
    <li>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Title)</li>
</ul>
}
```